# How do I make a smooth background-color change in Tailwind on hover?

Tags: tailwind-css, css-transitions

I'm trying to change the background color of an element on hover. Normally, I would use

`className='bg-white hover:bg-black'`

This changes the color instantly, but I would like to add 150ms of transition time from color A to color B.

After reading the docs, I tried something like

`className='transition-colors ease-linear duration-300 bg-white hover:bg-gradient-to-r from-[#04348B] to-[#0854e2d0]'`

This doesn't do anything. I have mixed and matched different states and such, and I can't find a solution. Anybody know a quick fix to this?

I tried:

`className='transition-colors ease-linear duration-300 bg-white hover:bg-gradient-to-r from-[#04348B] to-[#0854e2d0]'`

`className='transition-[background-color] duration-300 bg-white hover:bg-gradient-to-r from-[#04348B] to-[#0854e2d0]'`

Answer (score 7):

To create a smooth background-color change in Tailwind on hover, you can use the following syntax:

```
className='bg-white transition-colors duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-black'
```

#### Explanation:

- `bg-white` sets the initial background color of the element to white.
- `transition-colors` enables the transition effect for color changes.
- `duration-300` sets the duration of the transition effect to 300ms.
- `ease-in-out` sets the transition timing function to ease-in-out, which provides a smooth transition effect.
- `hover:bg-black` sets the background color of the element to black on hover.

You should avoid using two class attributes in one element, as it can cause conflicts and make your code harder to read. Instead, you can chain the classes together with a space between them.